# Is the fingering strange in Saint-Saens piano version (from Liszt) of Danse macabre

Tags: piano, fingering

In Saint-Saens piano version (from Liszt) of Danse macabre, m. 79,
there is this left hand fingering (that I show in blue)

Is it a good fingering ?
(it looks like 3 2 would be much more natural and easy)

[image: Liszt S.555 mm. 74–80]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right - swapped over makes more sense. Probably a misprint. Fingering is for guidance only, I encourage students to use what they consider best for them, which may be different from that printed. Suggest you do the same!

Comment: This information is capital. Let's see if somebody disagree or agree with you. I will validate your answer in 24 hours if nobody states an "opposite answer".

Answer (score 6):

This is an error in the score, which is corrected in the *Neue Liszt-Ausgabe* edition, shown below.

[image: Liszt S.555, mm.79–80]
(Image source: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Danse_macabre,_Op.40_(Saint-Sa%C3%ABns,_Camille)))